# How to implement multi-sig feature for dapp running on zksync network?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I'm building a Dapp that runs on Zksync network. and I need to implement multi-sig function
but Gnosis Safe doesn't support zksync network.
Can anyone advise how I can implement it on zksync network?
Thanks

I was tried to implement it using Gnosis Safe.
https://optimistic.etherscan.io/address/0xb074ec6c37659525EEf2Fb44478077901F878012